# What is the meaning of the superscript (1,0) that appears sometimes in the regularized confluent hypergeometric function Hypergeometric0F1Regularized?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

The last term in the following indefinite integral:

```
Integrate[k^3*BesselJ[0, k*r]/(k^2 + kappa^2)^2, {k, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {r > 0, kappa > 0}]
```

involves the regularized confluent hypergeometric function Hypergeometric0F1Regularized in an usual form with a superscript (1,0). How does this relate to the standard Hypergeometric0F1Regularized?

Thanks!

Comment: If you inspect the result with `InputForm[]`, you'll quickly find that that is intended to represent the derivative of `Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[a, z]` with respect to `a`. (Interpreted differently, you have the derivative of a Bessel function with respect to the order.)

Comment: @J.M. Ah thanks! Couldn't this be further simplified?

Comment: Simpler answer, try: `InverseMellinTransform[
  Integrate[
   MellinTransform[k^3*BesselJ[0, k*r]/(k^2 + kappa^2)^2, r, s], {k, 
    0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {r > 0, kappa > 0, 0 < s < 4}], s, 
  r] // Expand`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks for the comment. This potentially could be a good answer to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the answer involves the derivative of a Bessel function. Let's look at the result of the integral again:

```
Assuming[r > 0 && kappa > 0,
         Integrate[k^3 BesselJ[0, k r]/(k^2 + kappa^2)^2, {k, 0, Infinity}]]
   -1/2 (kappa r BesselK[1, kappa r]) + BesselI[0, kappa r] Log[2/(kappa r)] -
   Derivative[1, 0][Hypergeometric0F1Regularized][1, (kappa^2 r^2)/4]
```

Now, consider the following:

```
FullSimplify[D[FunctionExpand[Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[a, z]], a] /.
{a -> 1, z -> (kappa^2 r^2)/4}]
   -BesselK[0, kappa r] - BesselI[0, kappa r] Log[(kappa r)/2]
```

(The relevant simplification formulae in the DLMF can be found [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.15) and [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.38).)

Manually plugging this into the original result gives `BesselK[0, kappa r] - 1/2 kappa r BesselK[1, kappa r]` after simplification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are a few mistakes: We should get here $K_0(x)/4 - xK_1(x)/8$ with $x = \kappa r$. Just checked that numerically. There will be no logarithmic term here.

Comment: You might wish to note that `Log[1/(kappa r)] + Log[kappa r]` is a correction term that is zero almost everywhere. It looks like that *Mathematica* did not use the `r > 0 && kappa > 0` assumptions when I simplified it; so the simplest form should in fact be `BesselK[0, kappa r] - 1/2 kappa r BesselK[1, kappa r]`.